# C modify char** with strcpy

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I'm a little bit confused with pointers at the moment, could someone explain to me the reason why attempting to change a `char**` with `strcpy()` causes a `segmentation fault`?

```
void *change_string(char **string) {
 char *add = "Changed!";
 strcpy(*string, add);
 return 0;
}

int main() {
 char *p = "Original-";
 change_string(&p);
 printf("%s",p);
}
```

Comment: I was simply given "segmentation fault"

Comment: `char *p = "Original-"`  should be `char *p = strdup("Original-")`, if not , modifying `p` is an *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer `p` points to a string literal and you modify that string when you call `strcpy(3)`. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.